# TortoiseHg Workbench Graph symbols meaning

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

What is the meaning of the TortoiseHg Workbench Graph symbols?
I googled it and got only this (http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/workbench.html) but it has no description of the symbols. For example:

- Pentagon (that sometimes changes color)
- dashed branches
  [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Circle: public phase
- Pentagon: draft phase
- Square: secret phase
- Bar: close branch
  [image]
- Dash: graft
  [image]

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the Portuguese ;) (weird all my "Phase" columns have "public" as description, even the pentagons.

Comment: I thought would be funny for people trying to find what this secret project was about :) Some old versions of Mercurial/TortoiseHg had weird issues with phases. If your repository was made using a very old version, collateral effects can occur.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is also the "diamond" shape. It means it's a patch.

[image]